# yii2 captcha not change on page refresh

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am using the default captcha implementation of the yii2 advanced framework. I have a problem: I want to change my captcha code every time I refresh a page but when I refresh the page my captcha code does not change.

Comment: most likely the captcha  stored in a cash,

Comment: Please edit question and post some code, else, question will be closed, see help center.

Comment: There is no need to post any code I use the default captcha implementation

Answer (score 3):

The most correct solution will be to create your own `CaptchaAction`, that extends `yii\captcha\CaptchaAction` and override the `run()` method as follows:

```
namespace app\actions; // Change to your own    

class CaptchaAction extends yii\captcha\CaptchaAction {
    public $autoRegenerate = true;

    public function run() 
    {
       if ($this->autoRegenerate && Yii::$app->request->getQueryParam(self::REFRESH_GET_VAR) === null) {
           $this->setHttpHeaders();
           Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_RAW;
           return $this->renderImage($this->getVerifyCode(true));
       }
       return parent::run();
    }
}
```

Comment: when you do this it seems all is ok but when you want to refresh code with refresh link there is a problem because refresh link regenerate code and get the new hashes to validate in client side and when image requested it also regenerate code so validation hash is'nt valid

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<script>

window.onload = hello;

function hello()
{    
  document.getElementById('loginform-captcha-image').click();
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a dirty way round this - simply trigger the `click` event when the page loads. Add this code at the very end of your `view` file, after the end of the form;

```
$js = <<<JS
       $('#loginform-captcha-image').trigger('click');
JS;
$this->registerJs($js, $this::POS_READY);
```

It's not very pretty, but it works and it's the only way I've found to get aroun d this problem, which has also plagued my own sites.

Answer (score 1):

because you have set YII_ENV to TEST like this `defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'test');` change it to `defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'prod');`

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, just `unset` the session of captcha:

```
 session_start();
 unset($_SESSION["__captcha/panel/panel-auth/captcha"]);
 unset($_SESSION["__captcha/panel/panel-auth/captchacount"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(() => {
    $("#form-captcha-image").click();
  }, 100);  
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Update Your `CaptchaAction` as

```
public function actions()
{
    return [
        'error' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
        ],
        'captcha' => [
            'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
            'fixedVerifyCode' => null,
        ],
    ];
}
```

Read [Fixed Verify Code](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-captcha-captchaaction.html#$fixedVerifyCode-detail)

IF `fixedVerifyCode` if set then captcha is same as value setted in `fixedVerifyCode`

```
// code from yii\captcha\CaptchaAction in Yii2

public function getVerifyCode($regenerate = false)
{
    if ($this->fixedVerifyCode !== null) {
        return $this->fixedVerifyCode;
    }

    $session = Yii::$app->getSession();
    $session->open();
    $name = $this->getSessionKey();
    if ($session[$name] === null || $regenerate) {
        $session[$name] = $this->generateVerifyCode();
        $session[$name . 'count'] = 1;
    }

    return $session[$name];
}
```

Comment: This won't work as `fixedVerifyCode` is set as standard.