# Does not change captcha aftre refresh browser in yii2

Tags: yii2, captcha, page-refresh

I use default captcha in my project,I have 2 problem:

1- after refresh browser , don't change captcha.

2- The captcha does not expire when the user has not been active on page.

I also read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34401906/yii2-captcha-not-change-on-page-refresh) but But it couldn't help me. because It is set in my code YII_ENV_TEST to null. and  run action in actionCaptcha class have there is a way to change Captcha during page refresh Apparently!!.

I'm posting the codes here,However although these are the default code for using Captcha in Yii2.

in vendeor\yiisoft\yii2\captcha\CaptchaAction.php

```
class CaptchaAction extends Action
{

    const REFRESH_GET_VAR = 'refresh';

 .
 .
 .

    public function run()
    {

        if (Yii::$app->request->getQueryParam(self::REFRESH_GET_VAR) !== null) {

            // AJAX request for regenerating code
            $code = $this->getVerifyCode(true);
            Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            return [
                'hash1' => $this->generateValidationHash($code),
                'hash2' => $this->generateValidationHash(strtolower($code)),
                // we add a random 'v' parameter so that FireFox can refresh the image
                // when src attribute of image tag is changed
                'url' => Url::to([$this->id, 'v' => uniqid('', true)]),
            ];
        }

        $this->setHttpHeaders();
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_RAW;

        return $this->renderImage($this->getVerifyCode());
    }

 .
 .
 .


}
```

in controller/sitecontoller.php

```
 /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function actions() {

        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
            'captcha' => [
                'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
                'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
            ],
        ];
    }
```

in my view

```
<?php
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
            'id' => 'login-form',
            'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
            'enableClientValidation' => false,
            'validateOnBlur' => false,
            'validateOnType' => false,
            'validateOnChange' => false,
        ])
?>
 <?=
                $form->field($model, 'captcha')->widget(Captcha::className(), [
                    'captchaAction' => ['/site/captcha']])
                ?>
....
```

Comment: in siteController set `verifyCode => true`

Comment: @mohsen when i add verifyCode => true in siteController . don t load my captcha, I  add verifyCode => true in runActions, after fixedVerifyCode . : is this correct? public function actions() {
      
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
            'captcha' => [
                'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
                'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
               'verifyCode' => true,
            ],
        ];
    }

Answer (score 0):

[According to samdark in this url](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/17036#issuecomment-455903445)

> recommended

this option is not available and if you want captcha that change in every refresh you can create your own capcha class with extending captchaAction class

> not recommended

but it's helpful if you create javascript code that when page refresh click on captcha image you can achieve what you want.

Comment: I change $this->getVerifyCode() in run actioin ,(CaptchaAction) to  $this->getVerifyCode(true). But I do not know how to expire the captch, after being idle for a long time page

Comment: Is it what you need ? If you need create your own capcha class

Comment: As I said in second way ( not recommended ) you can handle that with javascript.
Its client side issue 
Put the second way to timer in javascript